# How do I host an MVC4 website using FTP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, publishing, filezilla

How do I publish and host an MVC4 website using FileZilla?

Please note that I am not using Azure.

I searched Google but couldn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean publishing to the general public? You need to find a web host that will cater to your needs.

The host must be capable of hosting an MVC4 application as well as having FTP access so that you can publish your application.

1. Use Google to search for an ASP.NET MVC4 web host
2. Sign up with your chosen web host
3. Use Visual Studio to Publish your website (perhaps locally to a file folder)

   - Solution Explorer
   - Right-click on your solution
   - Publish
4. Upload your files with the FTP server details provided by your host

If any step is unclear, search for tutorials or guides on it.

Comment: thanks Rowan, I am confused with your step 3.If you know any tutorial,then please tell

Comment: Is this helpful at all Athul?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34322t8f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx